# Is the reputation requirement to appear in the network reputation graph separate or combined?

Tags: discussion, reputation, stack-exchange, reputation-graph

> *Accounts must have a minimum of 200 reputation to appear in this graph*

Is the reputation requirement specified [here](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=reputation) combined from all Stack Exchange sites, or that the reputation in at least one of the sites must be >200? Or do we need to have >200 in every one which we have joined to appear in the graph?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The requirement applies to each individual site profile.  For instance, [my network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/72095/?tab=reputation) currently shows Stack Overflow, Law Stack Exchange, and Meta Stack Exchange, because those are the only sites on which I have at least 200 reputation:

[image: Graph showing lines for Stack Overflow, Law Stack Exchange, and Meta Stack Exchange]

There are other sites on which I have earned reputation that don't show, because I haven't hit 200 there yet.